# I am not able to get img src path is not loading in mail

Tags: php, html, email

I have created a cron job file for sending mail to customer at some time but the logo in mail is not diplaying, if have store all html data in variable with css design, in mail i am getting everything except logo, after inspecting mail, i saw that img src is empty, so i tried to store the image path in php variable and put it in between html code, still it didn't work, and i am using absolute path for image.

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Company name <senderemailid>' . "\r\n";
    $logo='https://www.assurancedentaire.ca/wp-content/plugins/InsuranceCalculatorCustom/assets/logo_assurance_dentaire.png';

    $email_body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <title>Title</title>
            <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:#333;">
     
            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#eee" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;color:#333333;padding:15px;" class="table_outside">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_full">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;padding:15px;background:#1fb9b9;">
                                         <img src='.$logo.' width="300" alt="assuranceplus"/>
                                    </td>';
           mail('recevermail.com', 'Application Form', $email_body, $headers);
```

[image]

Comment: Even though the image src is a non-broken string (no whitespace), it should still be surrounded by quotes in the generated HTML -- Edit, I see now that you're actually missing the first double-quote at the beginning of your string.

Comment: @aynber no quotes in generated html

Comment: you would be fine if you left the quotes off the img src, the issue is that you have the ending quote and not the starting quote. either add the starting quote or remove the ending quote.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. i think that is the problem let me check the output in mail

Comment: @SAWKk - That's definitely the issue. https://3v4l.org/evYuB

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. i have updated the code still same problem.

Comment: @SAWKk - at least your output is syntactically correct now. fyi, SO generally frowns upon editing your code to show what you've tried. better to just append the question. I provided an answer with something you can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a security issue due to your https, or the email client disabling network requests or something similar. I've had to convert images to dataURLs for emails in the past. Try this.

```php
$logo='https://www.assurancedentaire.ca/wp-content/plugins/InsuranceCalculatorCustom/assets/logo_assurance_dentaire.png';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($logo));
$logo = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData;

$email_body = '....<img src="'.$logo.'" width="300" alt="assuranceplus"/>...';
```

...Or, as you observed, most mail clients will not load images and external content when the message is filtered out as spam. Moving it to the inbox would resolve that particular issue.

Comment: Thank you for help sir, but i think problem is something else, still i have added your code to my code, let me check on diffrent mails, once i solved this issue i will update here.

Comment: got the solution, the images were not loading because the mails were comming as spam, as soon as i moved it to inbox the image loaded.

Comment: can you add this information in your answer, so i can accept it .

Comment: @SAWKk - ok done.